# Bootstrap carousel shows animation only in first slide

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

My bootstrap carousel has 4 slides and all of them have animated charts but the animation is seen only in first slide.
How do I ensure that the chart animations for the rest of the 3 slides are also seen?

Code :

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="trycarousel.aspx.cs" Inherits="trycarousel" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-sheets/bootstrap.css">
            <script src="css-sheets/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="charts/ChartNew.js"></script>
        <script src="css-sheets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">

                        <canvas id="canvas_Pie1c" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>

                    </div>
                    <div class="item">

                                           <canvas id="canvas_Pie2c" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>


                    </div>
<div class="item">

              <canvas id="canvas_Pie2c" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>
          </div>
<div class="item">    
         <canvas id="canvas_Pie2c" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>                        
   </div>
                    </div>
                 <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>

        </div>
                <script>
                    var mydata2 = [
                                {
                                    value: 0.39,
                                    color: "#18a5a5  ",
                                    title: "A"
                                },
                                {
                                    value: 10.13,
                                    color: "#3f51b5",
                                    title: "B"
                                },
                                {
                                    value: 44.29,
                                    color: "#df982f",
                                    title: "C"
                                },
                                {
                                    value: 45.19,
                                    color: "#668f4a",
                                    title: "D"
                                }
                    ];


                    var startWithDataset = 1;
                    var startWithData = 1;


                    var opt1c = {
                        animationStartWithDataset: startWithDataset,
                        animationStartWithData: startWithData,
                        animateRotate: true,
                        animateScale: false,
                        animationByData: "ByArc",
                        animationSteps: 50,
                        canvasBorders: false,
                        canvasBordersWidth: 3,
                        canvasBordersColor: "black",
                        legend: true,
                        inGraphDataShow: true,
                        animationEasing: "linear",
                        annotateDisplay: true,
                        spaceBetweenBar: 5,
                        graphTitleFontSize: 18

                    }
                    window.onload = function draw() {
                        var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_Pie1c").getContext("2d")).Pie(mydata2, opt1c);
                        var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_Pie2c").getContext("2d")).Pie(mydata2, opt1c);
                    }
            </script>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried this :

http://wenda.baba.io/questions/4163645/bootstrap-carousel-start-css-animation-after-slide-is-complete.html

So,I modified my code to this.I am not sure whether that post addresses my question.I just want animation to be shown in each slide which is presently happening only for the first slide.

My modified code according to the above article is :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <style type="text/css">

         </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-sheets/bootstrap.css">
            <script src="css-sheets/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="charts/ChartNew.js"></script>
           <script src="css-sheets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <style>

        body {padding-top:80px;}
        .inactive{opacity:0;}

        body {padding-top:80px;} .inactive{opacity:0;}
     </style>  

  </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">  

<div class="container" style="max-width:900px;">

      <div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide bs-docs-carousel-example">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">                       
                        <canvas id="canvas_Pie1c" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>                                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="item " id="z1">                    
                        <canvas id="canvas_Pie2c" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>                          
                    </div>

                   </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

</div>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="/bootstrap3/bootstrap-master/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>

    function transitions() {
        var j = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            setTimeout(
            function () {
                if (!$.support.transition) { $('#z' + i).removeClass('inactive') }
                else
                {

                    $('#z' + j).addClass('animated').addClass('fadeInLeft');
                    $('#z' + j).one($.support.transition.end, function () { $('#z' + i).removeClass('inactive') }).emulateTransitionEnd(2000);
                }
                j++
            },
            2000 * (i - 1));
        }
    }

    $('.carousel').carousel();

    $(".carousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
        if ($(this).find('.active').index() == 1) {
            $(this).carousel('pause');

            /* run your transitions */
            transitions();
            var that = $(this);
            /*restart your carousal */
            setTimeout(function () {

                that.carousel('next');
                that.carousel('cycle');

                /* hide transitions again */
                $("#slide2 [id^='z']").removeClass().addClass('inactive');


            }, 2000 * 5);
        }
    });


</script>
```

Still not working :/

I may be missing out something very simple/stupid. This is my first try at javascript.Please help.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Sure.Give me a minute.

Comment: Guys,any idea anyone ?

Comment: How do I improve this post's visibility ? There are on;y 20 views :/

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the chart animation on `window.onload`.Copy the same to **slid.bs.carousel** event. Check the below snippet.

```
$(".carousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_Pie1c").getContext("2d")).Pie(mydata2, opt1c);
var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_Pie2c").getContext("2d")).Pie(mydata2, opt1c);
});
```