# Prevent script from modifying specific object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem I have is that there's a bootstrap-slider in a bootstrap-slider in my website and firing the data-slide="next" button affects both of the sliders.

*Note: Code is not working in this example because it's drastically shortened to make it readable.*

```html
<div id="teasercarousel" class="teasercarousel carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="0">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <div id="subTeaserCarousel" class="carousel subTeaserCarousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item sub active">
          </div>
          <div class="item sub">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left carousel-control changeTeaser">
    <a href="#teasercarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right carousel-control changeTeaser">
    <a href="#teasercarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It currently removes the "active" class from the "#subTeaserCarousel .item" to. That shouldn't happen.

I hoped there could be a way to fix this problem without changing the bootstrap library script. I thought there might be something like that, that could work:

**Pseudo code:**

```
$(".changeTeaser").on("click", function() {
   ("#subTeaserCarousel").preventDefault();
});
```

Any other solutions which prevent the second slider from changing are also very welcomed.

Comment: I don't think nested carousels are supported directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081971/bootstrap-3-nested-multi-carousel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784138/bootstrap-carousel-inside-another-bootstrap-carousel for example.

Comment: Alright I'm probably rebuilding the sliding on my own then, thanks for the examples.